# using FormattedMessage in value attribute of input in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Is there any way I can use FormattedMessage inside value attribute of input in the code below? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<div className='flow_chooser actions'>
     <input disabled={model.isButtonDisabled}
      onClick={() => model.redirectTo(new_event_path(this.locale))}
      className='submit' type="submit" value={<FormattedMessage id="get_started" defaultMessage='Get Started' />}/>
</div>
```

I also tried to use call back function which worked correctly, but looking for more optimal solution:

```
<div className='flow_chooser actions'>
        <FormattedMessage id="get_started" defaultMessage='Get Started'>
            {(message: string) => (
            <input
            disabled={model.isButtonDisabled}
            onClick={() => model.redirectTo(new_event_path(this.locale))}
            className='submit'
            type="submit"
            value={message}
            />
            )}
           </FormattedMessage>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using the *imperative* approach.

```
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const intl = useIntl();

<input 
  value={intl.formatMessage({ id="get_started" defaultMessage="Get Started" })} 
/>
```

**Note**: Remember to wrap your root (App) with `IntlProvider` to be able to access the `useIntl` hook correctly.